# Function not getting stored properly in R console

Tags: r, rcpp

I have created a function mygrpc using cppFunction using Rcpp. When I call the function after starting the R session, I get the following error:

```
> mygrpc(xmc1,ygix,ygrpc)
Error in .Call(<pointer: (nil)>, x, ygix, ygrpc) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

xmc1 is a matrix of OHLC data of a stock, while ygix and ygrpc are functions that  act on the daily increment of the stock.

But when I rewrite the function again using cppFunction in Rcpp, and run it, it is getting executed. Even the function is getting displayed in the output of the ls() function.

I think the function is not getting stored properly, after I finish my session in the R console.

Any idea how to store the function properly so that I can use it again in my R functions without rewriting ygrpc again and again? If ygrpc is not stored properly, why is it getting displayed in the output of the ls() function?

Very many thanks for time and effort...

Comment: You need to create a _package_ to persist compiled code.

Comment: And please do NOT crosspost here AND on rcpp-devel.

Answer (score 2):

The R console does not store anything. R itself can be instructed to store the current workspace when quitting but this is generally a bad idea (and [should be disabled in RStudio](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/561146907519500288), if that’s used).

But this workspace image can’t store certain things, such as shared objects (which is what compiled C++ code becomes). Therefore you cannot persist the result of `cppFunction` across R sessions. You need to rerun the function every time your script runs. Or, as Dirk suggested, you put your code into a package and compile that instead of relying on `cppFunction`.